# Implementing functions returning match-based dependent types in scala 3

Tags: scala, scala-3

I'm experimenting with describing computations using functional composition in Scala 3. The goal is to be able to write something like this:

```
def doThat(v: Val[String]): Val[String] =
  v.maybeMap((s) => if s.length < 3 then () else s.capitalize) // fn1
    .map(_.substring(0, 3)) // fn2
```

The idea is that `Val` has semantics similar to `Option`, so fn2 would never be called for arguments shorter than 3 characters because fn1 would return Unit. Note that I don't just use `Option` instead of `Val` here because I'm interested in capturing the structure of the computation, not the result of a computation with a given argument, so `Val` is a placeholder for a value, not an actual value.

The goal is to be able to invoke `doThat` like this:

```
enum ValType:
  case Just, Option

class ValImpl[I](val t: ValType, val fn: ((Any) => Any) | Unit, val input: Val[Any] | Unit) extends Val[I]:
  // snipped

v = doThat(ValImpl(ValType.Just, (), ()))
```

and get a result that looks like `ValImpl(Just, fn2, ValImpl(Option, fn1, ValImpl(Just, (), ())))`

I defined Val the following way:

```
trait Val[I]:
  def map[R](fn: (Val.Unwrap[I]) => R): Val.SomeOf[R]
  def maybeMap[R](fn: (Val.Unwrap[I]) => R | Unit): Val.OptionOf[R]

object Val:
  type SomeOf[I] = Val[I]

  type OptionOf[I] = I match
    case Option[i] => I
    case _ => Val[Option[I]]

  type Unwrap[I] = I match
    case Option[i] => i
    case _ => I
```

The rationale for using dependent types for parameters of `map` and `maybeMap` is that if they are invoked on `Val[Option[I]]`, the `fn` would still be written with `I` as an argument. Further, `maybeMap` returns dependent type to avoid returning `Val[Option[Option[I]]` if invoked on `Val[Option[I]]`.

To this point it all compiles. However, now I am trying to implement `ValImpl` like this:

```
case class ValImpl[I](val t: ValType, val fn: ((Any) => Any) | Unit, val input: Val[Any] | Unit) extends Val[I]:
  // helps to make the code more readable
  private def eraseType[P, R](fn: (P) => R) = fn.asInstanceOf[(Any) => Any]
  private def eraseType[P](v: Val[P]) = v.asInstanceOf[Val[Any]]

  def map[R](fn: (Val.Unwrap[I]) => R) = this match
    case _ : ValImpl[Option[I]] => ValImpl(ValType.Option, eraseType(fn), eraseType(this))
    case _ : ValImpl[I] => ValImpl(ValType.Just, eraseType(fn), eraseType(this))

  def maybeMap[R](fn: Unwrap[I] => R | Unit) = this match
    case _ : ValImpl[Option[I]] => ValImpl[Option[R]](ValType.Option, eraseType(fn), eraseType(this))
    case _ : ValImpl[I] => ValImpl[Option[R]](ValType.Option, eraseType(fn), eraseType(this))
```

I am getting the following compilation errors in method `ValImpl.maybeMap`:

```
Test.scala:39:54
Found:    test.ValImpl[Option[R]]
Required: test.Val.OptionOf[R]
    case _ : ValImpl[Option[I]] => ValImpl[Option[R]](ValType.Option, eraseType(fn), eraseType(this))

Test.scala:40:46
Found:    test.ValImpl[Option[R]]
Required: test.Val.OptionOf[R]
    case _ : ValImpl[I] => ValImpl[Option[R]](ValType.Option, eraseType(fn), eraseType(this))
```

Please can someone explain why the compiler struggles with these lines? I cannot understand why `ValImpl[Option[R]]` in this case is not also `Val.OptionOf[R]`.

Any suggestions on how to fix this problem in the code are also appreciated.

Comment: In `OptionOf[I]` didn't you mean `case Option[Option[i]] => Val[Option[i]]`? Because with your code `Val.OptionOf[Option[String]]` is `String` and I believe you wanted `Val[Option[String]]`?

Comment: Good point! It should be case Option[i] => Val[Option[i]]

Answer (score 0):

I found a way past this once I realised that type calculations and the actual runtime behaviour exist independently. Even though the compiler tries to enforce alignment, it is not able to do so all the time, and at times you need to nudge it with `.asInstanceOf[]`. Perhaps it's completely misguided, but no matter what I tried I was not able to get it to realise that `Val.OptionOf[I]` is the same as thing as `Val[Option[I]]`.

I also realised that matching by the type parameter in the implementations of `map` and `maybeMap` is pointless as that information would not be available at runtime.

So, the working code looks like the following:

```scala
case class ValImpl[I](val t: ValType, val fn: ((Any) => Any) | Unit, val input: Val[Any] | Unit) extends Val[I]:
  // helps to make the code more readable
  private def eraseType[P, R](fn: (P) => R) = fn.asInstanceOf[(Any) => Any]
  private def eraseType[P](v: Val[P]) = v.asInstanceOf[Val[Any]]

  def map[R](fn: (Val.Unwrap[I]) => R) =
    ValImpl(ValType.Option, eraseType(fn), eraseType(this)).asInstanceOf[Val.OptionOf[R]]

  def maybeMap[R](fn: Unwrap[I] => R | Unit) =
    ValImpl[Option[R]](ValType.Option, eraseType(fn), eraseType(this)).asInstanceOf[Val.OptionOf[R]]
```